# Sending Image file from server to client in c++ windows

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, server, client

I am writing a code of **Image file** transfer using socket programming.
Here, client is sending one request message to server for some file to send to client. After receiving message from client, server is sending text file to client.
But now I need to modify this to receive Image file instead of text file.

Please help me to solve the code for image transfer.

Here is the Server and Client code

```
    //**server**
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <iostream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <string>
#define SIZE 10241
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")



using namespace std;

void send_file(FILE* fp, int clientSocket) {
    //int n;
char data[SIZE] = { 0 };



while (fgets(data, SIZE, fp) != NULL) {
if (send(clientSocket, data, sizeof(data), 0) == -1) {
perror("[-]Error in sending file.");
exit(1);
}
//bzero(data, SIZE);
//memset((data), '\0', (SIZE)), (void)0);
}
}

void main()
{
// Initialze winsock
WSADATA wsData;
WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

int wsOk = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);
if (wsOk != 0)
{
cerr << "Can't Initialize winsock! Quitting" << endl;
return;
}

// Create a socket
SOCKET listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (listening == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
cerr << "Can't create a socket! Quitting" << endl;
return;
}
else
{
printf("socket created \n");
}

// Bind the ip address and port to a socket
sockaddr_in hint;
hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
hint.sin_port = htons(54000);
hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY; // Could also use inet_pton .... 

bind(listening, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));

// Tell Winsock the socket is for listening 
//listen(listening, SOMAXCONN);
if (listen(listening, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
printf("Listen failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
}
else {
printf("listening...\n");
}

// Wait for a connection
sockaddr_in client;
int clientSize = sizeof(client);

SOCKET clientSocket = accept(listening, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);

char host[NI_MAXHOST];      // Client's remote name
char service[NI_MAXSERV];   // Service (i.e. port) the client is connect on

ZeroMemory(host, NI_MAXHOST); // same as memset(host, 0, NI_MAXHOST);
ZeroMemory(service, NI_MAXSERV);

if (getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client), host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXSERV, 0) == 0)
{
cout << host << " connected on port " << service << endl;
}
else
{
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
cout << host << " connected on port " <<
ntohs(client.sin_port) << endl;
}


FILE* fp = fopen("original.txt", "r");

// Close listening socket
//closesocket(listening);

if (fp == NULL) {
perror("[-]Error in reading file.");
exit(1);
}

// While loop: accept and echo message back to client
char buf[4096];

//while (true)
//{
ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
// Wait for client to send data
int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, 4096, 0);

if (bytesReceived > 0)
{
printf("Bytes received: %d\n", bytesReceived);
}
if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
//cerr << "Error in recv(). Quitting" << endl;
printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
// break;
}

if (bytesReceived == 0)
{
cout << "Client disconnected " << endl;
// break;
}
cout << string(buf, 0, bytesReceived) << endl;

// Echo message back to client
send(clientSocket, buf, bytesReceived + 1, 0);
send_file(fp, clientSocket);
printf("[+]File data sent successfully.\n");

printf("[+]Closing the connection.\n");


// Close the socket
closesocket(clientSocket);




//}



// Cleanup winsock
WSACleanup();
//system("pause");
}



//**client**

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#define SIZE 10241
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;



void write_file(int sock) {
int n;
FILE* fp;

char buffer[SIZE];

fp = fopen("copy.txt", "w");
while (1) {
n = recv(sock, buffer, SIZE, 0);
if (n <= 0) {
break;
return;
}
fprintf(fp, "%s", buffer);
//(memset((buffer), '\0', (SIZE)));

}
fclose(fp);
return;
}

void main()
{
string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";         // IP Address of the server
int port = 54000;                       // Listening port # on the server

// Initialize WinSock
WSAData data;
WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
if (wsResult != 0)
{
cerr << "Can't start Winsock, Err #" << wsResult << endl;
return;
}

// Create socket
SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
cerr << "Can't create socket, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
WSACleanup();
return;
}

// Fill in a hint structure
sockaddr_in hint;
hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
hint.sin_port = htons(port);
inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

// Connect to server
int connResult = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
if (connResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
cerr << "Can't connect to server, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
closesocket(sock);
WSACleanup();
return;
}



// Do-while loop to send and receive data

//int new_sock;
//struct sockaddr_in new_addr;
//socklen_t addr_size;
//char buffer[SIZE];

//addr_size = sizeof(new_addr);
//new_sock = accept(listen_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&new_addr, &addr_size);


char buf[4096];
string userInput;

do
{
// Prompt the user for some text
cout << "Write Data : ";
getline(cin, userInput);

if (userInput.size() > 0)       // Make sure the user has typed in something

{
// Send the text
int sendResult = send(sock, userInput.c_str(), userInput.size() + 1, 0);
if (sendResult != SOCKET_ERROR)
{
// Wait for response
ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, 4096, 0);
if (bytesReceived > 0)
{
// Echo response to console
cout << "SERVER :  " << string(buf, 0, bytesReceived) << endl;

write_file(sock);
printf("Data received successfully\n");
}
}
}
break;
} while (userInput.size() > 0);
//  close down everything
closesocket(sock);

WSACleanup();

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This code has a ton of problems with it, and needs a good rewrite. But to answer your question, open the files in binary mode, and use fread()/fwrite() instead of fgets()/fprintf().

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please help me with the code for the above mentioned doubt.